# How to change td or tr background color when data changes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using PHP and MySQL to select data from a table and display it in a div without refreshing the page, using jQuery, using a timed interval.  I'd like to be able to have the background color of the rows (or the individual cells) change, where the data changed since the last refresh.  Then, if a user clicks on the row (or td), it should change back to the regular color defined in the CSS.  I'm guessing I should use session variables in PHP to compare values between refreshes, but I don't understand how PHP is going to talk with Javascript since they are server/client technologies.  I've found one thread @ http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=191813 where a guy was looking to do the same thing and he figured it out, but I don't understand his code and it's bits and pieces of good and bad code.  Was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Edit:  Here is the code for the page that calls the php script to grab data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Tes View</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="offtime3.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#container").load('dcviewQuery.php');
var timer = null,
interval = 30000,

timer = setInterval(function () {
$("#container").fadeOut("slow").load('dcviewQuery.php').fadeIn("fast");
}, interval);

$(".dcview").live("blur", (function() {
if (timer !== null) return;
timer = setInterval(function () {

  $("#container").fadeOut("slow").load('dcviewQuery.php').fadeIn("fast");
}, interval);
}));

$(".dcview").live("focus", (function() {
clearInterval(timer);
timer = null
}));

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });    

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="viewajax-exec.php" method="post">
<div id="container"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for dcView.php, the bit that grabs the data from a table

```
$query="SELECT pID, fname, lname, offTime, pickUpTime, notes FROM mytable WHERE status <> 'Inactive' ORDER BY offTime";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
if($result) 
{
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    echo "<table><tr>";
    echo "<th id=\"fname\">F. Name</th><th id=\"lname\">L. Name</th><th id=\"date\">Date</th><th id=\"offtime\">Off Time</th><th id=\"pickup\">Pick Up Time</th><th id=\"notes\">Notes</th><th id=\"status\">Comp?</th>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    $num = 0;
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pid = $row['pID'];
        $tmptime1 = strtotime($row['pickUpTime']);
        $tmptime2 = strtotime($row['offTime']);
        $mydate = date("m-d-Y", $tmptime1);
        $cjdate = date("Y-m-d", $tmptime2);
        $putime = date("H:i", $tmptime1);
        $offtime = date("H:i", $tmptime2);
        $num++;
        if ( $odd = $num%2 )
        {
            echo "<tr class=\"odd\">";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr class=\"even\">";
        }
        echo "<input name=\"pid[]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$pid\" />";
        echo "<input name=\"jdate[]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$cjdate\" />";
        ?>
        <td id="fname" class="dcview"><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
        <td id="lname" class="dcview"><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
        <td id="date" class="dcview"><?php echo $mydate;?></td>
        <td id="offtime" class="dcview"><input type="text" size="4" name="offtime[]" value="<?php echo $offtime;?>" /></td>
        <td id="pickup" class="dcview"><?php echo $putime;?></td>
        <td id="notes" class="dcview"><textarea rows="1" cols="15" name="notes[]" wrap="physical"><?php echo $row['notes'];?></textarea></td>
        <td id="status" class="dcview"><input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="Inactive" />
        <?php 
        ++$i;
        echo "</tr>\n";

        }

        echo "</table>\n";
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        //Search failed

    }
}
else
{
    die("Query failed");
}

?>
```

I guess you can ignore the Submit button that calls viewajax-exec.php, since that script updates the data in the database, but I haven't been able to figure out how to send the data to the server without refreshing the whole page (but that is another problem for later).  I took out all my temporary bits of code that used session variables, because I was trying to figure out what flags were being set to what.

Comment: please provide some code or the markup you are working with

Comment: How are you updating the table? Complete wipe and redisplay? Updating invdividual cells/rows? How are you keeping track of what has changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing multiple rows and cells you could always say when the item looses focus, check to see if the previous value(from your database) is equal to current value of cell.  If different set the css to a different color.

```
var id;
$(":input").focus(function () {
id = this.id;});

$(":input").blur(function() { 
if this.id <> id
     //Call an update
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be something like this:

```
index.php
    ajax.js
    script.js
    result.php
```

`index.php`
Contains your HTML, and iterates through results obtained from `result.php` in order to create your table element.

`ajax.js`
Requests new results from `result.php` at a set interval. Compares the results to the data in the DOM of `index.php` and if there are changes, it updates the table along with assigning a `updated` class to updated items.

`script.js`
Some more JS, which includes a handler for clicking on items with a class of `updated`.

`result.php`
A list of results in JSON or some other format that is digestible by both PHP and JS.

If you give us some more details, we can add more of an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It really is difficult to say exactly what you need without seeing any of the code that you're working with or what you want to accomplish.

It sounds to me like you're looking for some kind of a ticker? Or maybe you want the user to see if someone else edited the table after their edit was made?

Nonetheless,

In any case, it sounds like you need some version control in your database if you hope to replicate this with any scalability. Try making a versions table and keep the data simple, such as relational ID of your data table, where the actual row data is kept, a column that describes what that data is (past version, current version, draft, etc.), and especially a date column. That way you can check and see if it was edited since your last refresh, and if it was, return it with a new class, or variable or something to indicate this.

If you want a version-type option, you probably need to add a column saying which user edited the info last, and then output the results, and give options for overriding later changes and things.